# Unable to encode context with utf8

Tags: json, django

I'm trying to get some objects for my javascript from my DB but I get the response with weird characters:

```
const rules = JSON.parse("&quot;[{\&quot;model\&quot;: \&quot;rules.rule\&quot;, \&quot;pk\&quot;:...
```

This is the view i'm using

```
def import_consumptions(request):
    try:

        rules = Rule.objects.all()
        rules = serializers.serialize('json', rules)
        rules = json.dumps(rules)

        context = {}
        context['rules'] = rules

        return render(request, "import_consumptions.html", context)

    except:

        template = loader.get_template( 'pages/error-404.html' )
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

And in my template javascript this is they way I get it:

```
const rules = JSON.parse("{{rules}}")
```

I know that must be something about encoding UTF-8 but i'm totally unable to get this.

How can I get all those objects without those characters?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using the template tag [json_script](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) from django in the template.